# html5 fullscreen jquery slideshow plugin (desktop)

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fullscreen

Is there a jquery slider plugin that enter in real system fullscreen?
All the plugins I found are fake and none of them enter in *real fullscreen*...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good full-screen slideshow:
http://eikes.github.io/jquery.fullscreen.js/

It uses the browser full-screen APIs, so it will display just like sites such as Vimeo and Youtube do when you set them to fullscreen.

It is built on jQuery and HTML5